# Using Bootstrap and ng-bootstrap is good?

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have two modules in my angular website , one is "bootstrap" and another one is "ng-bootstarp".

Does both modules are required , or any one is needed?

I am planning to keep only "ng-bootstarp" 4.0.0.0 and to remove "bootstrap"

Is this fine?

Also let me know the steps to remove "Bootstrap" ?

Can i just go ahead and delete the bootstrap from the ng_module folder or do i need to use any commands?

Comment: the first step would be to remove it and to see what breaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't delete it unless it's causing issues, Bootstrap is intended to be installed alongside ng-bootstrap.

Bootstrap is supposed to be installed when using ng-bootstrap, because ng-bootstrap 
relies on Bootstrap's CSS, but it replaces everything else that comes with Bootstrap, as you can see in their [dependencies](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#dependencies). The CSS is then set in your angular.json or imported into the main styles.css

That said, the non-CSS parts of Bootstrap are unused and could be deleted, but if you're using a package manger, e.g. NPM, this could cause issues when updating and you'll need to repeat this process each update.

As pointed out by @Eliseo, an alternative to using the normal Boostrap with everything included is to use bootstrap-only-css, which can be installed using NPM or Bower, details [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-css-only). This isn't an official Boostrap distribution as far as I can tell, so keep that in mind.

TLDR: there's no good reason to delete Boostrap.

Comment: i have an issue with bootstrap.min.js file, which is exposed for injection attacks, this url is directly accessible from browser ,entering url, i need to get rid of this. I thought it is comming from bootstrap but looks it needed

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't be directly accessible from the browser, there's no reason for it to be. The file isn't used as ng-bootstrap replaces this functionality, so I'm not sure how it's exposed for injection attacks? If you really need to you can delete this file, as I said ng-bootstrap replaces it, all you really need is whichever css file you imported. But you'll most likely need to delete it again whenever you update your dependencies. I'm also unsure why it's directly accessible via a URL, are you not using the prod flag for your builds?

Comment: @JoshDoug, ng-bootstrap only use bootstrap.css. So, you must **uninstall** bootstrap and install only the css: **npm install bootstrap-css-only**.

Comment: @Eliseo, thanks I wasn't aware of bootstrap-css-only, it doesn't appear to be an official project of Bootstrap though, but does look convenient if you're okay with the potential security & maintenance implications. As you can see in my answer I say that ng-bootstrap only uses the css, you don't have to uninstall the rest of bootstrap though, it's not doing any harm, it's just wasting a bit of space. That said, this might well be a good solution for this question so I'll add that to my answer thank you.

Answer (score -4):

Angular Material is the official UI framework for Angular, and is maintained (aside from open-source contributors) by Google engineers.

The community is fantastic, the documentation is excellent, and all of the components and utilities are designed to be used with Angular specifically. The source is a case-study in how to write code the Angular way.

It is for the reasons outlined above that I picked AM to be our company’s preferred UI framework.

I haven’t used Bootstrap in a very long time and I would not consider using it in a new project now.

Comment: ng-bootstrap is not bootstrap (only use bootstrap.css)

Comment: maybe but i am using bootstrap

Comment: bootstrap use jQuery, and Angular and jQuery is not a good combination. Of course you can use it, but the philosophy of JQuery and Angular is different (and in an Angular app, jQuery is not necessary)